# How to implement a search system in a database for an iphone application

Tags: iphone, sql, database, search

This is pretty wide question, but I'm hoping to get a push in the right direction (technologies and methodology).

Ok, I have an iphone app (which I am developing) that works with a web service (c#) through http requests. The web service connects to the underlying database, extracts the necessary data depending on the request and feeds it back to the application.

Now, I need to implement a search system in the app. The user searches for some words, and I need to provide the most relevant results. The search must be performed on different tables in the database.  Each table can be searched in a number of columns. For example, when searching through the people table I need to search in the first name, lastname, company, and other fields. Other tables have other important columns.

I have so many questions that I don't even know where to start.

How do I make my sql queries to make the search, but still be fast enough. Do I need to make some extra tables with indexed content somehow?
How should I add relevance factor to the results so I can ultimately filter only the most relevant results? For example, if an user searches for Smith, maybe there is a person named Smith or even a Company. They should be displayed before any other content that can have smith in the description.

I know the question is a little vague/wide but I can explain more if somebody desires.

Thank you

Comment: i'll be happy to accept an answer that points me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have decided to use Lucene. It's a wonderful piece of technology and even if I had some doubts in the beginning, after reading 3/4 of the book called "Lucene in Action" it was clear to me that it had everything I needed (and much more).

I know it's not a fully-functional searching system (with all the elements needed), but merely a library handling the core of a search system. It will need some work to integrate it with my application/webservice/database. I will let you know how it goes :)

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of depends on which language/rdbms you are using on your server. You might checkout various DB search solutions like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) which will do all of that indexing for you and provide a simple Search API. Sphinx for example allows you to prioritize columns, define character mappings (`ß->s`, `ä->a`) etc.

Comment: The db is Sql Server 2000 and the web service is in c#.

Comment: Sphinx looks good but I see is licensed under GPL. Commercial licenses are available but they probably need to be bought. At least for now, I'd like to search for a way without any extra costs to the client. If all fails, I'll consider Sphinx. Thanks

Comment: Sphinx itself is a stand-alone app, so the bigger issue would be, whether the c# client lib is GPLed or not (apparently it is). But as long as you just use it on your own/company's server, GPL won't force you open-source anything (AGPL would).